# Diagnosing a slow rendering fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

When running on a phone, my app swaps fragments into a main activity. When using the FragmentTransaction.replace() method on a particular often used fragment, I'm seeing a delay of about 2 seconds after onResume() before the screen redraws. The Choreographer complains of 100+ missed frames each time. There is a GridView and some buttons. The adapter and database access seems to be handling all their chores quickly prior to the delay. My best guess the layout may be inefficient, but I don't see how. Are there any tricks to diagnosing and optimizing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/content_background"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivFilters"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cd"
            android:background="@drawable/blank" 
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivReference"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cd"
            android:background="@drawable/blank" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivCabinet"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cd"
            android:background="@drawable/blank" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etSearch"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/et_search"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
            android:hint="@string/search" 
            android:singleLine = "true"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFilterName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/content_background"
        android:text="@string/all_recipes"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridDrinks"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="1"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Choreographer complains of 100+ missed frames each time

Then the problem is in your Java code, where you are tying up the main application thread.

> Are there any tricks to diagnosing and optimizing?

Start with enabling `StrictMode`, as my guess is that you are doing database I/O on the main application thread.

Then, if that does not point out any problems, use Traceview to determine precisely where your time is being spent.

Odds are, it has nothing to do with your layout resource.

Comment: Thank you. I'd forgotten about StrictMode for diagnosis.